# How can I add watermark logo on photo that I capture from my Samsung Galaxy S10?

Tags: photography, photo-editing

I want to add a watermark logo on the camera images that I capture from Samsung Galaxy S10.  Does anyone know about any tool/app for this?

Comment: Do you want the app to Run in your phone or PC? Which version of Ubuntu are you running on your phone or PC?

Comment: Hi Karishma, I suppose it would be better if you post this question in https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ forum instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use command like this:

```
composite -gravity SouthEast watermark.png input.jpg output.jpg
```

where the work after `-gravity` define the position of your watermark

The command `composite` is part of ImageMagic package. And keep the original photos!